# How to change amcharts5 gauge chart to make it fill up to a value

Tags: charts, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, amcharts5

I am currently using the amcharts5 gauge chart in a project for work and I have a functioning chart which looks like so:

[amcharts gauge chart with clockhand score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev6lp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev6lp.png)

This works fine and I can live with it, however I have been given a design which looks like this to work from:

[image: figma design gauge chart]

I was wondering if anyone knew if:

1. It's possible to create an amcharts gauge chart which only fills up to a given value
2. If so how to achieve it

Also, as a bit of a side note, if anyone could give me some ideas about how to make the chart use up all the space on the canvas whilst maintaining responsiveness that would also be awesome The image below should show what the issue is:

[image: gauge chart in dev inspector]

This is the code I used to achieve my working example (using vue 3 with the composition api and Nuxt.js 3):

```
<template>
    <div class="gauge-chart" ref="gaugeRef"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import * as am5 from "@amcharts/amcharts5";
import * as am5xy from "@amcharts/amcharts5/xy";
import * as am5radar from "@amcharts/amcharts5/radar";
import am5themes_Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated";

const props = defineProps({
    data: {
        required: true,
        type: Object,
    },
    gaugeBands: {
        required: true,
        type: Array,
    },
});

const gaugeRef = ref(null);
let root;
const axisDataItem = shallowRef(null);

onMounted(() => {
    root = am5.Root.new(gaugeRef.value);

    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

    const chart = root.container.children.push(
        am5radar.RadarChart.new(root, {
            panX: false,
            panY: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            centerX: 29,
            centerY: 35,
            startAngle: -240,
            endAngle: 60,
        })
    );

    const axisRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererCircular.new(root, {
        radius: am5.percent(100),
        innerRadius: -20,
        minGridDistance: 0,
    });

    axisRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
        stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
        visible: false,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
    });

    const axis = chart.xAxes.push(
        am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
            maxDeviation: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 60,
            strictMinMax: true,
            renderer: axisRenderer,
        })
    );

    axisDataItem.value = axis.makeDataItem({});
    const clockHand = am5radar.ClockHand.new(root, {
        pinRadius: am5.percent(50),
        radius: am5.percent(75),
        bottomWidth: 40,
        topWidth: 1,
    });

    const bullet = axisDataItem.value.set(
        "bullet",
        am5xy.AxisBullet.new(root, {
            sprite: clockHand,
        })
    );

    bullet.set("fill", am5.color(0x000000));

    axis.createAxisRange(axisDataItem.value);

    const label = chart.radarContainer.children.push(
        am5.Label.new(root, {
            fill: am5.color(0xffffff),
            centerX: am5.percent(50),
            textAlign: "center",
            centerY: am5.percent(50),
            fontSize: "2.5em",
            fontWeight: "bold",
        })
    );

    axisDataItem.value.set("value", Math.floor(props.data));
    bullet.get("sprite").on("rotation", () => {
        Math.round(axisDataItem.value.get("value")).toString();
        let fill = am5.color(0x000000);
        const value = axisDataItem.value.get("value");
        label.set("text", Math.round(value).toString());
        axis.axisRanges.each(function (axisRange) {
            if (value >= axisRange.get("value") && value <= axisRange.get("endValue")) {
                fill = axisRange.get("axisFill").get("fill");
            }
        });
        clockHand.pin.animate({
            key: "fill",
            to: fill,
            duration: 500,
            easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic),
        });
        clockHand.hand.animate({
            key: "fill",
            to: fill,
            duration: 500,
            easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic),
        });
    });

    chart.bulletsContainer.set("mask", undefined);

    am5.array.each(props.gaugeBands, (data) => {
        const axisRange = axis.createAxisRange(axis.makeDataItem({}));
        axisRange.setAll({
            value: data.lowScore,
            endValue: data.highScore,
        });

        axisRange.get("axisFill").setAll({
            visible: true,
            fill: am5.color(data.color),
            fillOpacity: 1,
        });
    });

    // Make stuff animate on load
    chart.appear(1000, 100);
});

onBeforeMount(() => {
    if (root) {
        root.dispose();
    }
});

watch(
    () => props.data,
    (newValue) =>
        axisDataItem.value.animate({
            key: "value",
            to: Math.floor(newValue),
            duration: 500,
            easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic),
        })
);
</script>

<style>
.gauge-chart {
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Not sure what your asking with `max` value since the code you gave already has `ValueAxis` with max of `60` set, like that is the answer right there in your code, so if your array input of values add up to `40` then `20` of the remaining points will be the grey and that's how it works?

Comment: As for the big whitespace, the only thing I can see that makes your gauge notably different from mine is that you are using a negative number for radius: `innerRadius: -20`, mine is set to `innerRadius: 70` and `radius:  100`.